# Target requires 8 element(s) but source may have fewer.ts(2345) TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, object

Im writing a type for a certain object as attached below.

```
export type HotelImagesType = {
  categories: never[];
  data: {
    [key: string]: imageArray[];
  };
  url_prefix: string;
};

//Here
type imageArray = [
  number,
  imageTagsOne,
  number,
  imageTagsTwo,
  string,
  string,
  string,
  string
];

type imageTagsOne = tags[];

type tags = {
  confidence: number;
  photo_id: number;
  tag_id: number;
  tag_name: string | null;
  tag_type: string;
};

type imageTagsTwo = tagsTwo[];

type tagsTwo = {
  id: number;
  tag: string;
};
```

I get the above error **Target requires 8 element(s) but source may have fewer.ts(2345)** and i have a few questions.

**Question 1) What is target and source in context of typescript?**

**Question 2) How do I fix the error Target requires 8 element(s) but source may have fewer.ts(2345)?** I have attached the actual object below if it is of any help.

I have narrowed down the problem to the **imageArray type**. This is the description i get from typescript

**Type '(string | number | ({ tag_id: number; confidence: number; photo_id: number; tag_type: string; tag_name: string; } | { photo_id: number; tag_id: number; confidence: number; tag_name: null; tag_type: string; })[] | { ...; }[])[]' is not assignable to type 'imageArray'.**

After reading a few questions on the same here at stack overflow i have some general idea that the syntax of my type strictly needs the array to have 8 elements inside the object which might not be the case for some of the arrays.

I however cannot identify what is causing this problem. Is there a way to like  "Loosely" type the type definition? because when i log out the target values chrome says all of my arrays have 8 elements. I dont get it please help.

Comment: it's not entirely clear, but are you trying to assign the provided object to a `HotelImagesType` type instance?

Comment: @roomcayz exactly. Im using the type for the provided object

Answer (score 0):

## answer on question 1:

target - the "thing" you are trying to assign to, pass value to, etc.

source - the actual value, type, etc.

```js
const xdasdasd: ABC = 333;
//    ^target         ^source
```

## answer on question 2:

your type definitions are invalid (or rather to say: not matching the data, or the other way around): `tag_name` is `null` in one of the branches of the object (and `null` type can not be assigned to the `string` type)

ts has quite decent error detection, but the error messages are far from readable, usually the last message from the compiler points you out what's the problem, but in your case I used the ts playground to identify the error

[image: ts-playground error]

so defining the type as following fixes the error:

```js
type tags = {
  confidence: number;
  photo_id: number;
  tag_id: number;
  tag_name: string | null;
  tag_type: string;
};
```

[ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=268&ssc=25&pln=268&pc=29#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcASEbADYEkC2AhgObADOAKsqgLxwDeAsAFBxwDGhWx0AluQC44AO2AA3YFADaAXQDcLNgBMuhIU1Zs4UgNbBEQsjCi9hxGUN5FSAQShRCiWQs0BfF2wCuUbAH0wUMAAZrwghsamxC7uLCxIKHBWJMB2DohwdFKKIp74AEaSADTZSaQUJGQA8qLFmsK5BVC1bKXA5cSUAO4QzXBGJma9-ZFDEYPZw2Ys8rHM8ait7VWiGQgVzrPzax2rGmzsEMIhSsDC7MBC9fmSHnBgABaYEL68SpcNN9kwJC9vOddQW7fYi%20YSEfAXPpjKJfH7zcIDGHMGLMOLURLWNoVCjdVbAroQDaoubo-E4iC7Ep-K6NIEkBGRaIuFgHYRGOBhdCYHAEZKUdF0PZwABEnG4fHIwqEsl6wpU3ylDGybGFACYAKwATlVABZFVlNFptMqjXAAIy9U3Gw1WpU220i4G%20eaK4X4Pz44WWh2On5giGugBCXHuUAgEHwXpNDtFh2Op3OirNAAZk96Y07XkmLdHbcKHk9forVSXVQB2Ctms25o2udOmoU%2030gl1CN0eipR%2015p3%204CugDSvBg7HupwA9EOR2PRDAsF2myrM0pFQA2etW2NHV4J-tCTVpmum-OPGDPLNCUvlyvV7u1o8yDdwK8VstVp8GpuNn3Ci-m9UAMxPkawrAkGIZhhGwpHmwdYwXai7Nq6AAKYYoLAiALouv4rkIKapgRqa3k2rgPk%20wrjiA8qEOOrRkOOp44OORAgCmuogGWq4ABzji%20N4AHQAFZgMQAD8Og0MmZbJmaZZKOq6pKDqq7qsAgGalxeTsHJhCqsmqrAAB7BKABwAqUEQQAVxyYaQB0lcewqZ5BWmoAcmSjJgBOqATqqp5GahAAGQQDQWGbpR1G0Zi9GMdgzGECAbnJrxpavlWQkieJknSbJ8mKcpqnqZp2kqHpBlGSZZnqhZVk2VxdnJg5TkuW5HleT5fkBcFoXkRFqhRXyDHcnFLHqqmKUlmlZoZWJElSTJckKUpKlqQBGlaTpZWGcZpnmZZ1m2fZjnJs5Zaue5nneV5nVBSFYXHn13wDaQMXDeOZAAI6eIQgSrslfFvtNwmzdlC15cthVrcVm36dtlV7bVh2Ncdp3nW1V2%20f5t2hbmj65p%20to5ne1pfvBKqsvGZx7nAmplsBWigT8f5mpq9MqgWZ5FkI6pllqXGaqzZPNqC4LU8KqEQOhSBwIGni8NgSiRPdGZwtQrrus6nbwaRxN48TPN8wLH7wd%20MZ-kBQuM8QKFoZI0t5HLCtK9r9Omz2JCugAIo4yt5n%20OrET6cHE2wbubmBbYS1LmFsyKzOEYRgcOjrDp6zGj00XRQ1YCNCVsTqHHceOBsaQLM1ZYQXHAEoeSro57Cqq5ml5ABZpKUE5ZKEoq6qgBGq6pqgFmkEZqrkEhCEABQTADqeRcR3ZZ5B5g9KGaZnANXQR5N1vsqhnz3kNnTEsUlxe86XmrlxJlfV7X9eN1ZeQt23OoL13Pd9%20qA9DyPY8T1PM854LyXjZRSa9VwbyUFvHevUqL9SzrFeKIAxrJRLvzS%20wMK5VxrnXZMDcm5P1bu3Tu3de79x1IPVuv9x6T2nrPee5YQEr3AZA6Bd1YGRQQW9T631fqoPPugq%20NAb44PvgQ5%20xC5KkM-t-Kho8aEAPocA5eYD16b23ndXG9YCZWiJg6HRtow7Hl7KLV0AAZCAT9EDjgAErAHOGAGAvBDi72MarFA6sOwdFcSBZcip1Sxy3JTRMQguIBMthzc8uFzRVmTKuAOqouLazIkeKsKZ4lmkScbEOCFsIRxFBYqxcBoBwECA4pxLjAnMz%20i7E2lt8ni1thhHxDN44JyIsk3WHD4HRSPrnVi%20kC6cR4mkuJCSuJCK4lXKeMk24FHVOwPuAFAKqiCJqDy5wl482ACzKeXdlnry4rPVclV5K6R2ewPIiTx5eTLDqGBR4KJwKelwnOSDT6jIyYkyZ0ygizJrmpRZvcVlrI2cALZZYdmuSCPs1SECjm11Oeqc5ZpLnXMnjqO5DziZPM4b0xBo1xqfPGT8wyfyqwAoWUskF6y8HgvkpC3ZMKTJwuAAik5pkzkGVRVc%20eGKsXsMefvV5TEeE-TMslYlmSJmYIklMsl-z5lAuWX3UFdKIVQr2Syw5xykUorRXy259zNHdjTqaAxRo9G2gtQ2epfpTFtgoAANXHAAUWEFgWAhBTAQg9XAAAwqcT1LSlzuLFhrT0gS-F4VVIEimO4qaKlpoEyJXM4DDMSQpVUtSclGN8fagMbZAzVxDcLVsIoI2dhTaeKJioM1hK-lGpm0SzQWxyeTOMCaQk0zLJ01OT561ZuyaTdtSE2zexjpbf2SdbTBxHYhHCSYyxtoXQ05CNbilBAQGOOAnRHjYFQJBSMOb515I9m2Gx4ZIxVJbe01M2ackp1tGa8KzzM74reixfOhceKDq-kI1cq5CDJkIOwIIq4AJuWACdaemTP6mU1A3EyAdu5BG8uwQDq9kwb35vEwgqL1Q6mTIRjycldQTyCNi9Ob6D6vTeSfcaf7VQAaAyBsDEGoMwZ2WQwCwBEOqmQ23Me6HMMphw5qPDBGiMkakkocjhBKOCpxcKj99GEooPHExljwHQPgcg9hrjcGNQIaQ15ITaGFmiew2yiTOp8PsEI8RnUpG5N2YU1RvMKnBqILFXwzT3FM3-tlTQQDOn2P6eg3kWDPGTMCbM6hkTJyxM2ckw56TznZPycUzjU12jUkfhfaaT5ZpALriPDao0ebWktrLLGu11s2yVBgGOKA0FH0pOUzRkV-Tv3DPHMV0rQjEMmSMiPSyiTFllj%20VvAKmLghKE4JPUqAnOAOWANJbS4HCBP01MB6ya8O5Edq7JDzr68Xec-QlD5sTVwlYAquIbO1RvDz7g5Oy02sZzZhYtgCy2FuV3OBtqbQGdt7ZksEXUUlVQnaU9R87L0%20lII0wN%207j2RtgZexN97yYZuEC%20-9pbukVsA-W3g4H228i7cauDw7UOYc9SFV11Toqvrir%20v1m7d2HvBeG5BjH423tTZx59yF33-5-dW4DsnW3QfU4O5D47ZYd5aPxvl8rdTR1WzTZk6thY-wvhUuqLicbO0nETfuOm9XnRqzbJW7xTaQR9ldM6t1Hq7beuEL6%20Aga3etZPT6KrobHcOpFMWlcDvrceNt14sgpaTx6%20iQbhSxurfMxXdheNZvu20z7c%20p8SejcFe6S85nPXBk-omuWQ3MrMoSTEyWc6N9gCEE4pqQytX2DsEQyVssGHsPxN%2043Liq8tQATnqmTgfkMNKAPJpbyCmoGnYekzi7anErjQLzXkG9eH4gars31v7fVSd%207zzPvZkdSD40iP1y4%208G6S0ic2feR58wuy643FPTV-H3Uxv1K1ehEd9G998W9Vw287Jj8u92Ae9z8B85Nr8Stb9rJ78p8n9GoX9kU38l8QIvMEcfNWc-NN9ADsMG83Im9QDwCO8oCYC-oL8r9h9ECx9kDJ9H8Z90DX9F8TUrRCs2AKtzRh0A8rcnci0S0I9y12xNZ7cIka1tciNG51QqwdQI808Tdtws9qYNJc9uCnwzQ5DB5FCi9Gd4dD4CU85y8%20tdD9J9DdDJk-kuJj84lQMKEzITgrJAJkwdQ1INQlB5U3IjIdQMNVwyxCAfDOVdRnJqppIN5dRlIX81l39i931v9%20kPk9CFCbDgt55GoHCgN2BnCTlDIwk3JPCv5FJfDPI8jAjgjQjq5wjeYggojgAYjVw4jNQEijCv88DLtkEiU0jFDbDsjHJcj8jXCiiPCvCyjpkKiAjANqj6pajZ56jGjmjWj2jOtjC6MWdeEJV%20s%20iMja8aAsj7ChinC28Ci3DiiJifCpj-CqiQj5jXMIiGjrMVjX42jldctVdiYrUrQ%20DQ5pCE8kw%20jW5lCW108mwgku0NDLdNcTFC1Q9RCrdxC7dY9-cHRA8y0bcK0Y8484SxYXd3VPVvgfUg0A0g1JA49M9dwk1wSfxo1zQ6tNdU1mZgSZ0rQn1tDUlWTDD1jOiTDujesi5LD5DW0gYDjW4KEGjdI0NOAZk8gv5Z5EMJ5uJFk55VRJ499VJywR4qxIUYiG5jISxTJCAmjl1uJsCGZcD%20S19UirCFDW4hEJS2jgjVkAjaEToFTKdFsVSmD1SyCwlTSdTZImidQAjj85Ne5m9TT7suILS94V8ui19kdWTHTdDnTpS3S5TPSlTCAfS1SNTK4tSps0k9TQyDSIzjTozzTYdPMEzrSti2dJUUzgsnSpTXTZS-l5Twicy8z7CCyAztSSyQywzDTIyTTywYyPjOTuw%20CfjzUNdV1m1sxVDglqZ8JddOYWSrCdQuIVIxCsSJDI0hCQ9hRgxmsj02sSJXYATNyW09Cdy9zU9okzoVyoSk0U9YSC1qZ6hsBsB9yo9sTJDUT2sukuTtzdzwliY-jckITmZAIHdwJzyr1Lyg5rzNc2l2k5yVYGsRQo47ZMItDTQeDLS6zNiy92ILD7yIKhFPC%205N59kPIfCoE7lFI2824NJj9asotu5hNp4psu9YZ3JJ5TJfItRe4749J1Q4yRQrSyL3lejwKVIaLDIDIoEGL3Jh8GjvIZ8dkZ9jiuKYVAM0M%20KggBKDIhLIMZ4NRtQx865JLpLP8S9kikcFLG4Hz1RlK6K1KTJGLNKWKdL2L9K-JDLeL1tTKDxzKVBLLRKbKJLiMHLZLEdfMdjhTNR3LPLVLmVfsNLmLtK2K9LOLgqeLjKwqzLoMoqRLrLxK7L4quCiKTQZBsg50RRvA-AAhghQhXR7g5wwAyABBxxxwwN%20I8gjAuBeB2B%20IDhj1kQgA)

Comment: i have fixed the type but that does not seem to change anything. Please try look at the updated question

Comment: In my work when I don't know with what shape of data I'm dealing and I have a sample of them, I'm using tools like https://app.quicktype.io/ to generate the types and avoid human mistakes, also: I updated the answer to include solution, please notice the typescript version as well

Comment: app.quicktype.io just saved my ass . However your answer did not fix the problem so I'm kind of torn whether or not to accept it. .

Comment: @AmosMachora which ts version are you using? Because as you can see on the screenshot I don't even have the same error on v4.8.4